# Error: Unable to create an object of type "ApplicationDbContext"

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I had moved the ApplicationDbContext to a different project, and I can no longer update my database.

ApplicationDbContext and Solution structure:
[image]

Here is my Program.cs in project PMSX.WebApp:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var services = builder.Services;
var configuration = builder.Configuration;

// Add services to the container.

//Database (Persistence)
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AzureSqlConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'AzureSqlConnection' not found."); ;
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
```

Here is my ApplicationDbContext.cs:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Portfolio> Portfolios { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StockHolding> StockHoldings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're keeping the DbContext in a different library, you can do something like this.

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AzureSqlConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'AzureSqlConnection' not found."); ;
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, 
assembly => assembly.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext ).Assembly.FullName));
});
```

Make you've added the reference of the class library to the web app.

Comment: I am sill getting the same error "Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. Do you know if I can just reset everthing?

Comment: I think you need to configure one more constructor for DbContext class, like this.


public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
{
}

protected ApplicationDbContext()
{
}